# Custom Policy-Based Authorization with asp.net Core, Problems with the View

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I implemented Custom Policy=Based Authorization as per https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html.

This ended up being successful when it was accessed via the [Authorize] in a controller.  However when I attempt to use it in my view as below.  I get in issue with the context.Resource being null.

I am new to mvc so any help is appreciated.

View

```
@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "IsRegisteredUser"))
{
     <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Solution" asp-action="Index">Solutions</a></li>
}
```

Authorization Handler

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsRegisteredUserRequirement requirement)
   {

            if(context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var mvcContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.AuthorizationFilterContext;


            }


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you can use the overload method of AuthorizeAsync with the resource parameter set with the ViewContext:

```
await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, ViewContext, "YourPolicyName");
```

Then in the handler you can cast the resource to ActionContext base class, from which ViewContext and AuthorizationFilterContext inherit:

```
var actionContext = context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext;
```

You then have access to the HttpContext, ModelState and RouteData.